# Dúvida na passagem de parâmetros via AJAX para Action ASP NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, visual-studio, asp-net-core

Amigos, estou tendo dificuldade na hora de passar um valor para a Action de um controller específico que recebe como parâmetro um id do tipo int.

**AJAX**

```js
var dataForm = $("#statisticId").val();


        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "Statistic",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataForm,
            success: function (_response) {
                console.log(_response);
            }
        });
```

**Action Statistic**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Statistic([FromBody]int dataForm)
{
    var statistics = statisticPatientBLL.GetStatisticById(dataForm);
    return Json(statistics);
}
```

Já verifiquei se está realmente passando qualquer valor, e sim, ele exibe corretamente quando coleto o value de um elemento HTML. Não consegui encontrar uma resposta pra isso. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Seria algum problema na questão de rotas? O que há de errado nesse código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já conseguiu resolver seu problema, mas deixo aqui algumas correções nas configurações do seu AJAX, talvez te ajude:

```
var id = $("#statisticId").val();
    console.log(id);

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "text/plain",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Answer/Statistic/",
        data: id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (_response) {
            console.log(_response);
        }
    });
};
```

No exemplo acima ao invés de concatenar na **URL** utilizei o parâmetro `data` para definir o valor a ser enviado no `post`. Veja mais sobre os [**parâmetros de configurações do AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Um problema que também percebi na configuração do seu `AJAX` é que o `contentType` está como `application/json`. No seu caso como você está enviando apenas um '**id**' você deveria usar `text/plain`, conforme está no meu exemplo.

Comment: George, fiz as alterações seguindo sua estrutura, mas não consegui obter o valor do id. O que poderia ser neste caso?

Comment: @FelipePrestes, percebi agora que deixei essa parte data: id, sem virgula, acabei de editar e coloquei ela, deve ser isso.

Answer (score 0):

consegui identificar o erro. Estava faltando adicionar o caminho completo na URL no AJAX.

O trecho corrigido ficou assim:

```
var id = $("#statisticId").val();
    console.log(id);

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Answer/Statistic/ " + id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (_response) {
            console.log(_response);
        }
    });
};
```